# Might a cast iron pan set on top of a microwave oven affect the operation?

Tags: home-experiment, microwaves

Our microwave *seems* to take longer to get the job done these days. I notice that someone is storing a large, heavy cast iron pan on the top of the microwave. Is there any way at all that it is possible that the iron pan is interfering with the microwave?

I could try with/without the pan but it isn't that dramatic.

Comment: Your italicization of 'seems' indicates that you should firstly determine *objectively* whether the MW still operates as normal or slower than normal.

Comment: I've removed a comment that should have been posted as an answer.

Comment: This really isn't a physics question, but one more about the operation of an everyday device. I don't know that there's any particular SE site about such subjects, but I disagree that it's this site.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos, this is definitely about physics. In the usual "operation" of a everyday microwave you don't put a pan on top of it. Can't see why this is inappropriate for this SE, this could even be a question on an intro E&M exam

Comment: @KFGauss no it really isn't about physics. it's about why OPs microwave isn't working as he (for whatever reason) expects. that's vague (which makes it broad) and not about physics concepts in any way (except that microwaves use E&M)

Comment: Cant write a legit answer since it was put on hold (unfairly, imho). But, the cast iron pan might be influencing the magnetic fields inside of the magnetron that generate the microwaves. An increase/decrease of the magnetic field changes the frequency of the electron orbits in  the magnetron, and if they dont match those of its cavity, the output power is decreased. This should be reversible though, have you tried taking the pan out and seeing if that helps?

Comment: @Gyromagnetic I returned to this question having the same thought as yours. Could the heavy iron (magnetic) material be distorting the magnetic fields produced by the magnetron which in turn are responsible for generating microwaves?

Comment: The magnetic interference was my original concern. However, since there is a known cause of degradation of performance that is more likely I consider the question resolved. Thanks to all for the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have not drilled holes into your microwave (that can be really dangerous and should never be done) the enclosure forms a Faraday cage from which the microwaves cannot escape, therefore they can also not interact with the iron pan.

However, with some imagination one could certainly come up with weird reasons why a heavy weight on the top might influence, let's say, a part of the control circuit. Therefore I suggest you replace the iron pan with a stone of similar mass to assess if it is the weight or the ferromagnetic and conductive iron that causes the effect.

Comment: There is no a Faraday cage in a microwave oven. Instead it uses a 1/4-wave choke to seal the cavity around the door.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating a bit on terri's answer... If (big, hypothetical if), some object like the cast iron pan were reducing the energy going into the food, then it should be heating up. But, a big hunk of metal in firm contact with the Faraday cage that is your oven's enclosure should at most act as part of the cage.

Metal objects will in general, respond to microwaves in either of two ways (depending on how things are arranged): (1) Eddy currents will be induced in the metal; it will absorb energy and heat up. (2) It will reflect the microwave energy.

As microwave ovens age, the power they deliver does drop for a few reasons. One of them is as follows: There is a "window" between the oven's main compartment and the emitter; this window looks opaque but is transparent to microwaves. It can accumulate contamination from spilled/spattered food which will reduce the amount of energy that can pass through, reducing the amount of energy that goes into your food.

Comment: That was a very helpful answer. It even gives me something to look at to maybe clean it up and get it operating better. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Ruminator I think the "window" requires a bit of care when cleaning; might be best to do a bit of research on it.

Comment: In addition (this is getting more into DIY territory than Physics), the window (which is generally made of mica/silicone-resin sheet) is replaceable. Contamination of the window not only can reduce effectiveness, but can lead to arcing, which is a more serious matter. The sheets themselves don't cost much, and any reasonably handy person can replace them.

Comment: You're assuming the pan was absorbing energy rather than in some fashion limiting the energy that goes through it.